# how to deploy netbeans Qt project to stand-alone executable

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans, deployment

I'm working on a netbeans c++ Qt project in Ubuntu. I would like to deploy this program to a stand-alone executable that can be run from Windows machines.

I can't find anything online on how to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to compile the source on a Windows machine or set up a cross compiling toolchain.

I highly suggest the first option as the second isn't any fun.

Then you will either have to statically link the proper Qt dlls and compile them into the final executable or simply copy the required dlls into the path of the executable. What's the easiest way to figure out the required dlls? Try to run the program, it will fail and tell you which libraries you need to link to it. (Or run an ldd on ubuntu and keep track of the list)

(Note:I think statically linking the libraries may have licensing implications. It has been a while since I looked at the Qt licenses.)